# I have root to my unix machine, how do I reset my MYSQL root password?

Tags: linux, mysql, unix, database, password

I cannot login to MySQL

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/86587/what-is-my-mysql-root-password/86588#86588

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the solution here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a question asked a lot, there is of course a section on it in the official MySQL manual: [B.5.4.1. How to Reset the Root Password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html)